# Passing json data to online server from iphone its storing empty data in my online database

Tags: php, ios, iphone, json

Hi in my application I'm storing the data in sqlite3 database and I'm passing as a json to my server side script where i have put the code to insert in online server I'm using the php script . Everything works fine but in my online server its storing the empty data.

```
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field1Str] forKey:@"name"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str] forKey:@"city"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field3Str] forKey:@"phone"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field4Str] forKey:@"email"];

        [array addObject:_dataDictionary];


        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSURL *someURLSetBefore =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://indianpoliticalleadersmap.com/IOS/trail/insert.php"];
        [request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        // print json:
        NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
     } 
    }
```

When i log the json its showing like this format.

> [{"name":"sdfsdf","phone":"0","city":"dsf","email":"dsf"}]
>   2014-03-19 20:06:21.567 database[2576:70b] JSON summary: [{"name":"sdfsdf","phone":"0","city":"dsf","email":"dsf"},{"name":"sdfsf","phone":"13123123","city":"13123123","email":"sdfsdfdsfsd"}]

If i print the array which i have stored the data dictionary its showing like.

> [array addObject:_dataDictionary];

```
{
    city = "selva kumar";
    email = madurai;
    name = 8870882627;
    phone = "shantharsk@gmail.com";
},
```

If i print the  individual fields the fields in my above code field1Str,field2Str.....

> name:Aswin,city:karnanataka,phone:133213232,email:vvvvvv

This my php code for inserting into my online database.

```
  <?php 

     $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
     $obj = json_decode($json);

     //echo $json;

     //Database Connection
  require_once 'db.php';

     /* insert data into DB */
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db512172115`.`trial` (name, phone, city, email) 
      VALUES ('".$obj->{'name'}."', '".$obj->{'phone'}."', '".$obj->{'city'}."', '".$obj->{'email'}."')");

     //database connection close
 mysql_close($con);

   //}
  ?>
```

Please tell where I'm doing where in this above code why its not storing in my database please give some solution i have been stack with this for long time I'm not able figure out its eating my head.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `var_dump($json);` and `var_dump($obj);` ? before inserting into the DB?
it seems that you are sending an array that has one object so try the below:

`$obj[0]->name; // etc ...`

$obj will contain an array, if the json string contains an array with objects, to answer your question in the comment below, you can find below how to declare an array:

```
$myArray = array('a','b');
```

or associative array like below:

```
$myArray =  array('a' => 'a value', 'b' => 'b value');
```

*Going Back to your specific case:*

if you have this json string in the php server side:

```
[
    {"name":"sdfsdf","phone":"0","city":"dsf","email":"dsf"},
    {"name":"sdfsf","phone":"13123123","city":"13123123","email":"sdfsdfdsfsd"}
]
```

You will need a loop to go throw all objects in your array and insert them like below :

```
 <?php 

     $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
     $obj = json_decode($json);

     //var_dump($json); // you can use var_dump for debug.

     //Database Connection
      require_once 'db.php';

     /* insert data into DB */
      foreach ($obj as $element){
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db512172115`.`trial` (name, phone, city, email) 
      VALUES ('".$element->name."', '".$element->phone."', '".$element->city."', '".$element->email."')");
      }
     //database connection close
      mysql_close($con);

   //}
  ?>
```

Comment: pls tell how make array declaration $obj[] = json_decode($json); is it correct

Comment: i have did something i like u told its giving sytax error can u please check where im doing wrong here declaration $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$obj = obj('na','ph','cit','em');

Comment: in this code its showing syntax error VALUES ('".$obj('na' => 'name', 'ph' => 'phone', 'cit' => 'city', 'em' => 'email')");

Comment: it seems you are going out of topic in your comment questions, please take a look at this page : http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
this shows how to declare and how to use arrays.

Comment: @user3427551, Did that answer your question ?